# Notification on my screen

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Can someone tell me what kind of notification is this one on my status bar, I mean the one in the middle, between my phone signal and Wi-Fi signal?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This icon means **Call forwarding**. This icon appears when call forwarding is turned on.

Here is a list of such icons :

[image]

You can find more about these icons in the following pages.

1. [Windows 10 mobile icons - Micosoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/getstarted-icons-cortana-mobile)
2. [Windows Phone 8 mobile icons - Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10932/windows-phone-what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean)

Answer (score 3):

That's a [Call Forwarding](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/calling-and-messaging/calling-options) icon. It means that you have call forwarding turned on for that specific number/SIM card you are using in this device.

[image: Windows Phone Notification icons]