# Incoming phone calls are automatically forwarded on Nokia Lumia 530

Tags: 8.1, calls

Incoming phone calls are automatically forwarded on Nokia Lumia 530
(Windows 8.10)

I want to end this feature. Not sure how it got enabled.

A small icon is shown at top of my status bar: phone horn icon with small arrow pointing to the right.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Settings->Phone.
2. Turn off *Call forwarding*.

> A small icon is shown at top of my status bar: phone horn icon with
>   small arrow pointing to the right.

You can refer to this [answer here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13043/18061) to know more about icons in status bar.

Comment: That link is to not to a specific answer?

Comment: @RowlandShaw My mistake. Thanks for letting me know. Updated the link.